# redirect to another site from the URL with argument

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

```
redirect /index.php?categoryID=647 http://other_site.ru/
```

That is precisely this category store a reference to another site. In this form, does not work. I suspect that the problem is due to an argument. How to do the right thing?
Sorry for bad english (google translator)

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Describe the behavior you observed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in a redirect. You need to use mod_rewrite and match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^categoryID=647$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://other_site.ru/? [L,R]
```