# redirect to another site from the URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How to organize a redirect from a certain section of the site to another site?

```
http://site1.ru/category/stroitelstvo-domov/
```

to

```
http://site2.ru
```

Please help!

Comment: What is the question here? This is already answered thousands of millions of times on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean simply?

```
Redirect /category/stroitelstvo-domov/ http://site2.ru/
```

Comment: It's so simple? I tortured RewriteRule by analogy with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385789/redirect-to-another-site-from-the-url-with-argument I'm stupid.
Thanks!

Comment: @lrbis80 yeah, you don't have any query strings so it's pretty basic.